# How to access external usb camera on unrooted android devices

Tags: android, android-ndk, v4l2

I want to access extern usb cameras via v4l on android.

I tried [SimpleWebCam](https://bitbucket.org/neuralassembly/simplewebcam). After some slight modifications of the original source codes, i achieved to make it work on a rooted android device. However, on unrooted devices, it keeps complaining about "not have permission to access "/dev/video*".  I checked the permission of /dev/video* with "ls -l /dev/video*", and got

`crw-rw---- system    camera    81,   0 2015-08-18 18:31 video0`

I understand that it means /dev/video* are owned by system, and are readable/writable to users in group "camera". So I think if i add

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`

in the manifest of my app, the user id of my app will be added to the group "camera", then my app will be allowed to read data from /dev/video*.

But, it still complains about "not have permission to access /dev/video*" now.

i also tried

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

, but still not working.

Do i miss somthing or misunderstand somthing. Any help or discussion will be appreciated.

The codes i used to open device are

```
int opendevice(int i)
{
struct stat st;

sprintf(dev_name,"/dev/video%d",i);

if (-1 == stat (dev_name, &st)) {
    LOGE("Cannot identify '%s': %d, %s", dev_name, errno, strerror (errno));
    return ERROR_LOCAL;
}

if (!S_ISCHR (st.st_mode)) {
    LOGE("%s is no device", dev_name);
    return ERROR_LOCAL;
}

fd = open (dev_name, O_RDWR);// | O_NONBLOCK, 0);

if (-1 == fd) {
    LOGE("Cannot open '%s': %d, %s", dev_name, errno, strerror (errno));
    return ERROR_LOCAL;
}
return SUCCESS_LOCAL;
}
```

The return value of open is always -1, with logcat:

```
 Cannot open '/dev/video3': 13, Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2):

I finally achieve to read images from the external usb camera on unrooted android devices using an opensource project named uvccamera.
Here is the link, https://github.com/saki4510t/UVCCamera

Answer (score 0):

Try to add also

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

in your manifest file:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, i am now off work and will try it tomorrow.

Comment: could you post your whole stacktrace?

Comment: the stacktrace may not help in this case. instead, i paste the codes i used and the corresponding logcat here. hope it helps.

Comment: well, that's pretty interesting, if I were you I would add all of the permissions to the manifest file, just to try if there is a permission for this :/. Here is the list for all of them: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html